# Load user profile data from sqlite database into user Profile in android and edit it

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created an android app and have been able to create user table in sqlite and register user. I wanted to login to the app as the user using username and password and get directed to their profile. The login part is completed now the problem is to load the sqlite database data into user profile.

Here's the DataHandler class

```
public class DataHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public final static String col1 = "Id";
public final static String col2 = "Name";
public final static String col3 = "Email";
public final static String col4 = "Mobile";
public final static String col5 = "Password";
public final static String col6 = "Address";
public final static String col7 = "Category";
public final static String col8 = "Wages_per_hour";
public final static String col9 = "Experience";
public final static String col10 = "Job_Description";

private static final String DB_NAME = "UtilityNp";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 6;
public final static String Table_NAME = "Worker";

public final static String STRING_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_NAME + " ("+col1+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT 1, " + col2 + " varchar(25) NOT NULL, " + col3 + " varchar(25) NOT NULL, " + col4 + " varchar(25) NOT NULL, " + col5 + " varchar(25) NOT NULL, " + col6 + " varchar(25) NOT NULL, " + col7 + " varchar(25) NOT NULL, " + col8 + " varchar(25) NOT NULL, " + col9 + " varchar(25) NOT NULL, " + col10 + " varchar(25) NOT NULL);";
public final static String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_NAME;

   public DataHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}
SQLiteDatabase db;
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(STRING_CREATE);
        System.out.println("oncreate called");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
        System.out.println("onupgrade called");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
public DataHandler open(){
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close(){
    db.close();
}
public long insertData(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e, String f, String g, String h, String i)

{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(col2,a);
    cv.put(col3,b);
    cv.put(col4,c);
    cv.put(col5,d);
    cv.put(col6,e);
    cv.put(col7,f);
    cv.put(col8,g);
    cv.put(col9,h);
    cv.put(col10, i);

    return  db.insertOrThrow(Table_NAME, null, cv);
}

public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
{
    Cursor cursor=db.query("Worker", null, " Name=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Password"));
    cursor.close();
    return password;
}
```

}

It's the login class.

```
    public class Login extends Activity {

Button login;
EditText editTextUserName, editTextPassword;
DataHandler loginDataBaseAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    loginDataBaseAdapter=new DataHandler(this);
    loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

    login =(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);

           // get the Refferences of views
  editTextUserName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
    editTextPassword= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);



    // Set On ClickListener
   login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {
           // get The User name and Password
           String userName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
           String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

           // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
           String storedPassword = loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);

           if (userName.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0) {
               if (password.equals(storedPassword)) {

                   Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                           //Starting a new Intent
                           Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), User_Profile.class);
                           startActivity(nextScreen);

               } else {
                   Toast.makeText(Login.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           } else {
               AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
               alertBuilder.setTitle("Invalid Data");
               alertBuilder.setMessage("Please, Enter valid data");
               alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       dialog.cancel();

                   }
               });
               alertBuilder.create().show();
           }


       }
   });


}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Close The Database
    loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
}
```

}

Now after logging i want the user to get directed to this activity with user's information in it.

Here's the xml file.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#e8e8e7"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Your Profile"
            android:textColor="#2582C5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:background="#f3f3f3"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/name"/>
        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:background="#f3f3f3"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/email"/>
        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Mobile"
            android:background="#f3f3f3"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/mobile"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:background="#f3f3f3"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/psw"/>
        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Address"
            android:background="#f3f3f3"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/ad"/>
        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Category"
            android:background="#f3f3f3"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/cat"/>
        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Wages per Hour"
            android:background="#f3f3f3"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/wages"/>
        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Experience"
            android:background="#f3f3f3"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/experience"/>
        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Job Description"
            android:background="#f3f3f3"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/jdesc"/>


        <Button
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.18" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If anyone can help me out i would be thankful.

Comment: What's the error? You need to fetch the data form the database in your `User_Profile` class's `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Run Select Query to fetch user's Record
- if Cursor is not null means record returns
- loop through the Cursor Obj
- pass each cursor Column to a Variable e.g. 
  String FName = cursor.getString("FName Column")
- Pass the Variables as an Extra to.Intent that will start UserProfile Activity 
  E.g. Intent intent = new Intent (CurrentActvitiy.this, UserProfileActvitiy.class); 
  intent.putExtra("FName", FName);
- Start the Activity after adding all the Data you need to add 
  E.g. startActvity(intent);

INSIDE the UserProfile Activity onCreate Method

Get the incoming Data like this: 
Intent incomingData = getIntent(); 
String userFirstName = incomingData.getString("FName"); 
Pass the data retrieved to Views 
E.g. 
FNameTextView.setText(userFirstName);